# Filling Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: fortran, derived-types

I have created a derived type to access multi-dimensional arrays. With each array I associate a name in the array nm.

My problem consists how to fill the array values once I have allocated the memory.

An initial idea has been to use a multi-dimensional array as input. However I might run into memory problems if I store two copies as the arrays can be big. A better idea might be to pass a one-dimensional array with data along the first dimension and a specification on the position of the second and third dimensions where the data should reside.

I would value some suggestions on possibly better ways to fill arrays to derived types if there are people who have experience working with big data sets.

```
Type :: Multia

  Character (Len=65) :: nm(3)
  Real, Allocatable :: ma(:,:,:) 
  Real, Allocatable :: mb(:,:,:) 
  Real, Allocatable :: mc(:,:,:) 

  Contains
    Procedure :: set

End Type Multia


Subroutine set (m, nm, u, i, j)

  Class (Multia), Intent (InOut) :: m
  Character (Len=65) :: nm
  Real, Intent (In) :: u(:) 
  Integer, Intent (In) :: i, j

  If (nm .e. (m% nm(1))) Then
    m% ma(:,i,j) = u
  Else If (nm .e. (m% nm(2))) Then
    m% mb(:,i,j) = u
  Else If (nm .e. (m% nm(3))) Then
    m% mc(:,i,j) = u
  End If

End Subroutine set
```

Comment: You don't give how the components are allocated, but have you considered `move_alloc`?

Comment: I use a normal Allocate (m% ma (la,lb,lc)). Was not aware of move_alloc. I wonder how the deallocation is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is about the duplication of arrays such as in

```
m%ma = [...]  ! Humongous array
```

then Fortran 2003 offers the `move_alloc` intrinsic which moves the allocation (including the values) from one variable to another.

```
Subroutine set (m, u, v, w)
  Class (Multia), Intent (InOut) :: m
  Real, Intent (InOut), allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: u, v, w

  call move_alloc(u, m%ma)
  call move_alloc(v, m%mb)
  call move_alloc(w, m%mc)
End Subroutine set
```

called something like

```
type(Multia) m
real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: u, v, w
! ... allocating and setting u, v, w
call m%set(u, v, w)
! Components of m now allocated, u, v, w, not allocated
```

From the notes (in Fortran 2008) of that intrinsic:

> It is expected that the implementation of allocatable objects will typically involve descriptors to locate the allocated storage; MOVE ALLOC could then be implemented by transferring the contents of the descriptor
>   for FROM to the descriptor for TO and clearing the descriptor for FROM.

That is, the expectation is that there will be no copying of data or array temporaries.

This assumes, of course, that you can't just allocate the components of `m` and assign there directly.

Comment: I will fill an array by reading data from a file, then move the values to one of the arrays in Multia. Yes, my concern is about the duplication of arrays so that I do not get a situation where there is not enough physical RAM to store both. And thinking about it, also on the inefficient use of an actual allocate and copy.

Comment: You're going to have to do at least one allocation (I'll assume you have some form of dynamic memory use), but `move_alloc` should avoid the copy and duplication and the allocation will be very cheap compared with reading from file.  You could read from file directly into the components of the `Multia` type, but that's a design choice: hopefully the approach here gives you a choice of whether you have a distinct array for some form of encapsulation.

Comment: Perhaps also worth adding that this approach means that there needn't be an initial/distinct allocation for the components of the derived type.  Even if they were allocation initially, they would be deallocated before the allocation is moved.